# How to delete a Spring MVC model attribute in JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I am setting a model attribute in controller like

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/searchMessage.htm" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String searchMessage(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) throws CoreException {

    if (request.getParameter("mode") != null)
        model.addAttribute("mode", "mode");

        return null;
}
```

In My Java script i use the model attributes as

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var value = '${mode}';
});
```

Now i want to reset the model attribute called "mode" in my Js because it retains the value everytime the page is refreshed. Actually, i want to use the value only once during the first load of the page.

Comment: I agree. You need to put some code to we take a look,]

Comment: Thanks. I have modified my code above. Please take a look @Shreyos Adikari

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to solve? What is the problem even if the `model-attribute` is retained on page-refresh?